# How to add one code to four classes?

Tags: java, class

I have a code which is done coded but I realized its hard to see in the code so what I want do is to add four classes which one will be for Viewer, UserInput, Player and Controller.

- The viewer is to see the game information (Which is the JPanel most of all)
- UserInput is to let the user choose options with buttons.
- Player is where the computer information will be (Functions for the CPU)
- Controller is where all the mathematics will be, New game (Restart when pressing New game Button), Make points and so on.

So I made a class where it should start all the classes with by run that class

```
            SSPPlayer player = new SSPPlayer();
            SSPViewer viewer = new SSPViewer();
            SSPController controller = new SSPController();
            SSPUserInput userInput = new SSPUserInput();

            JFrame frame1 = new JFrame( "SSPViewer" );
            frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            frame1.add( viewer );
            frame1.pack();
            frame1.setVisible( true );

            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame( "SSPUserInput" );
            frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            frame2.add( userInput );
            frame2.pack(); frame2.setVisible( true );
        }
    }
```

However, The problem is now that I have made so far two classes which should be in each window for Viewer and UserInput but I could only get viewer to work.

**Viewer class**

```
public class SSPViewer extends JFrame{

    private JPanel  resultatPanel;
    private JLabel  infoLabel, resultatLabel;
    private JTextField UserResult, CompResult;


    SSPViewer() {
        super("SSPViewer");
        setSize(600, 400);
        UI();
    }

    public void UI() {
        Container container = getContentPane();  

        resultatPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));  
        resultatPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        UserResult = new JTextField(" Dina vinster:  ");
        resultatPanel.add(användarResultat);
        CompResult= new JTextField(" Datorns vinster:  ");
        resultatPanel.add(datorResultat);
        infoLabel = new JLabel("Börja spela genom att ", JLabel.RIGHT);
        resultatPanel.add(infoLabel);    
        resultatLabel = new JLabel("använda knapparna längst ner!", JLabel.LEFT);
        resultatPanel.add(resultatLabel); 
        container.add("Center",resultatPanel);

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    }
}
```

**UserInPut Class**

```
public class SSPUserInput extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    final int ROCK = 0, Sciss = 1, Paper= 2;


    private JButton Rock; 
    private JButton Scoss;  
    private JButton Paper; 
    private JButton newgame, exit;
    private JPanel  UserPanel, UserPanel1;

    SSPUserInput() {
        super("SSPUserInput");
        setSize(800 , 600);
        UI1();
    }
    public void UI1() {
        Container container = getContentPane();  

        UserPanel= new JPanel();
        UserPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,4));
        UserPanel.add(new JLabel("Du väljer här:", JLabel.CENTER));
        Rock = new JButton("Rock");
        Sciss  = new JButton("Sciss");
        PAper = new JButton("Paper");

        Rock.addActionListener(this);
        Sciss.addActionListener(this);
        Paper.addActionListener(this);

        UserPanel.add(rock); 
        UserPanel.add(Sciss); 
        UserPanel.add(Paper);

        container.add("South", userpanel);

        UserPanel1= new JPanel();

        newgame= new JButton("New Game");
        exit= new JButton("Exit");
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        UserPanel1.add(exit);
        newgame.addActionListener(this);
        UserPanel1.add(newgame);
        container.add("North", UserPanel1);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int val = 0;

        if(e.getSource() == exit) {

            System.exit(0); 
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == newgame) {

        }
        else if (e.getSource() == Rock) {
            val = Rock;       
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == Sciss) {
            val = Sciss;
        }
        else {
            val = Paper; 
        }


    }

}
```

So I was wondering now why it doesn't work. It seems like I have done it right but...

It would be easier too me and you if anyone is available teamviewer or skype.

EDIT: If there is something you don't understand in the code. Just comment!

ERRORS IM GETTING IS FOLLWING:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
    at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at Redovisning3.Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

**SLOVED THIS PROBLEM. To solve this problem which I had before was to just let row 15 and 22 be as a comment for a while until you have done your all classes.**

Comment: "it doesn't work" is basically meaningless. What happens? You get an error? If so, do you get a compile error or an exception when running it? What is the error? Your code is also using an object användarPanel which seems to appear out of thin air.

Comment: Im sorry for being like that, im just little bit frustrated but anyways, im trying to translate all the codes from swedish to english so there might be some that arent translated but anyways. whats happens is that the window from Viewer is popping out without any problems but not the UserInput. getting like 7-8 erros ect. at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)


Possible that you have skype or teamviewer, would be easier for me to explain for you too @Gimby

Comment: Don't comment, add missing information to the question. Don't describe the error, post the exact error. Don't request personal chats, that is not how this works.

Comment: Oh okey @Gimby Im kinda new in the fourm so it was great that you told me this. Never knew it. Anyways I just posted everything that should be in the question.

Comment: The stack trace very clearly identifies line 15 in Test.java, so why haven't you shown us line 15 of Test.java? Also if you arrive in a new place it is common etiquette to [read the rules first](http://stackoverflow.com/help) ("New to Stack Overflow? Take the 2 minute tour.").

Comment: See also http://sscce.org/ for troubleshooting tips.

Comment: I didn't realized it until you said it.  

frame1.add( viewer ); and then it says row 22 getting error after i make the frame1 as a comment, so i made a // on both and so there is no error now. but stuffs that are in UserInPut doesn't show in the window.

Comment: @ThrillOfit Then again see http://sscce.org/. After you have attempted to investigate and narrow down your problem, you may just end up solving it yourself, and learning a lot in the mean time. If you have not, once you have your minimal example, then come back here with a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

**I have done and wrote how to solved the problem I had before (Incase someone is having same trouble as me in the future). However there is another problem which now contain a if-else statements. 
So I have a class which allows you to pick SCiss, paper and rock. Which of these has they own number.**

> Rock = 0, Sciss = 1, Paper = 2.

**I have following using this in one of the class because it is needed to know what button you are pressing.**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int val = 0  ;

    if(e.getSource() == exit) {

        System.exit(0); 
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == Newgame) {
       //Nothing here yet.
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == Rock) {
        choice = Rock;       
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == Sciss) {
        choice = Sciss;
    }
    else {
        choice = Paper; 
    }
    Sum(choice );
```

**and what I trying to do is when you are pressing one of these three buttons it should save the Number in sum(choice) and then go to another class to make other functions, by that I mean this:**

```
 public void berakna(int val){
        Userchoice = choice ;     
        Compchoice = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
        resultatLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0); 
        infoLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);   
        infoLabel.setText("Result round" + ++round +":");   

        if (Userchoice == Compchoice )
            resultatLabel.setText("Tie!!");   
        else if (Userchoice == Rock &&  Compchoice == Sciss|| 
                Userchoice == Sciss &&  Compchoice == Paper ||
                Userchoice == Paper &&  Compchoice == Rock ) {
            resultLabel.setText("You win! One more time?");
            UserResult.setText(" You won: " + ++UserWin + "pcs");
        }
        else { 
            result.setText(" You lose, Try one more time!");
            CompResult.setText(" Comp won: " + ++CompWin+ "st");
        }
    }
}
```

**I was thinking using return, so I tried but it didn't got me any forward. So ideas would be greatful. There is also no errors.**